# what are the directives that support one way binding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In angularjs what are the [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that support oneway binding. `ng-model` supports two-way binding 
Does `ng-bind`,`{{ }}` expression supports one way binding ?

Comment: Yes..`ng-bind` & `{{}}` do one way binding, what is the question then?

Comment: ng-repeat, ng-switch and ng-include by default supports one way binding, as they create new scope

Answer (score 3):

In fact by default AngularJS work with 2 way data-binding when you use `ng-model`. `ng-bind` is exactly equivalent to `{{ }}`, and **yes** it's a one way data binding used for displaying the value inside html component as **inner HTML**. Which is also important is that `ng-bind` be used along with `ng-model`.

In order to have one way data-binding you can also implement a custom directive with **isolated** [scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). In isolated scope there are 3 types of binding options used as prefix to your variables as follows:

- `@` used for Text Binding
- `&` used for One-way Binding
- `=` used for Two-way Binding

in your **JavaScript** file:

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])  
  .directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
      restrict: "AE", // A refers to a html attribute, E refers to a html element
      scope: {
        text: "@attrText",
        twoWayBind: "=attrTwoWayBind",
        oneWayBind: "&attrOneWayBind"
      }
    };
  }).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.info = {name: "dhia", age: 25};
    $scope.text = "Text to be displayed";
});
```

**HTML**

```js
<div ng-controller="myController">  
  <div my-directive
    attr-text="{{ text }}"
    attr-two-way-bind="info"
    attr-one-way-bind="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

***NB:***

- Text bindings they are always **strings**.
- One-way bindings can be of **any type**.
- Two-way bindings can be of **any type**.

If you are kind of new to [AngularJS directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), I will recommend to go [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/) to have a better idea how a **custom** directive is implemented and what are the different **directive types** and about the **attribute naming** conventions.

Answer (score 1):

A data binding can be specified in two different ways:

with curly braces: `{{expression}}`

with the ng-bind directive: `ng-bind="varName"`

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

**It is on you how you want to use your scope see angular site for one way data bind**

http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/onewaydatabinding/

```
<body ng-app ng-init="firstName = 'John'; lastName = 'Doe';">
  <strong>First name:</strong> {{firstName}}<br />
  <strong>Last name:</strong> <span ng-bind="lastName"></span>
</body>
```

**and this is for custom directive**

https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/